# Why code gives error even though llvmlite.dl is in specified directory

Tags: python, llvmlite, rembg

```
from PIL import Image 
from rembg import remove 
import glob 
import os

input = Image.open(file)
output = remove(input) 
output.save(f"{file}.png")
```

Why code gives error even though llvmlite.dl is in specified directory "**OSError: Could not find/load shared object file: llvmlite.dll Error was: Could not find 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\llvmlite.dll' module (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.**"

I tried uninstalling, added path to llvmlte.dll in path environment variable, both methods didn't work